# How do I put a blank line in redmine wiki?

Tags: redmine, wiki

I am just wondering how I can put some blank line in redmine. What I tried is putting the following text:

```
some sample txt



with a few empty lines
```

What I got in redmine is

```
some sample txt
with a few empty lines
```

So, how can I let redmine to display these empty lines? I tried using whitespace, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a pretty ugly solution, but it gets the job done (on [demo.redmine.org](http://demo.redmine.org) which currently runs with redmine version `2.5.0.devel.12954`):

```
some sample txt
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
with a few empty lines
```

is displayed as

```
some sample txt



with a few empty lines
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this, it solved my problem. I don't really need any beautiful solution as I'm only working with a small project.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way: If this solution solves your problem, you might want to accept it (so that others see that the question is answered).

Comment: Just did, stackoverflow requires some time gap between the time you posted your answer and my acceptance.

Comment: Beautiful (but still ugly) solution! Been wanting to do this for a while as quite often separate sections of a wiki or list get very cramped together and the odd line break makes it so much better to read.
Funny how a non-breaking space gives you a line break though...

Comment: I think the non breaking space forces the wiki to recognise the line. You would get the same affect if you put a character in there. It stops the engine from ignoring blank lines, because it is no longer blank.... just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
<pre>
blah blah blah


A few lines down
</pre>
```

Which will look like:

```
blah blah blah


A few lines down
```